# How to apply requirement traceability in my StarUML project?

Tags: staruml

Although I'm aware that StarUML does not have the requirement diagram feature but, I wish to use an available diagram to create different requirements and then map each requirement to use cases, activity diagrams, class diagrams etc., and consequently have a trace from a high-level requirement to the details present in the downstream region of the model.

Is there a way to implement such a traceability in StarUML?

Thanks in advance.